# the size for values of type `[bool]` cannot be known at compilation time, when using IndexMut

Tags: rust, indexing, slice, wrapper

I'm trying to use the Bitmap class as a wrapper for bools. As such I want to be able to index using slices and assign to slices. I'm coming from a python background so I'm used to things just working. In python you basically define **index** and **len** and you're good to go. Obviously rust is more complex with typing and ownership and sizes. I really like it though and want to learn about how it works. Please be patient with my lack of understanding. I am a noob to rust, but not to coding, although most of my experience is with dynamic languages.

In effect, I want this struct to behave like an iterable, which is to support indexing and slicing and so on. I think the solution may have to do with Sized, but I can't say for sure.

```
struct Bitmap <const N: usize> {
    bools: [bool;N],
}

impl<const N: usize> Bitmap<N> {
    fn new(bools: [bool;N]) -> Self {
        Bitmap { bools }
    }
}

impl<Idx, const N:usize> std::ops::Index<Idx> for Bitmap<N>
where
    Idx: std::slice::SliceIndex<[bool]>,
{
    type Output = Idx::Output;

    fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.bools[index]
    }
}

impl<const N: usize> std::ops::IndexMut<usize> for Bitmap<N> 
{
    fn index_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut Self::Output {
        &mut self.bools[index]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut test = Bitmap::<6>::new([true, false, true, false, true, false]);
    //Indexing works
    println!("{:?}", test[0]); 
    //Index assignment works
    test[0] = false; 
    //slicing works
    println!("{:?}", &test[1..]); 
    
    //But does not work when you do it like this
    let slice = [2..5].as_slice();
    println!("{:?}", &test[slice])
    //error[E0277]: the type `[bool]` cannot be indexed by `&[std::ops::Range<{integer}>]`
    
    //Slice assign does not work
    //test[0..2] = [false, true]; 
    //error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[bool]` cannot be known at compilation time
}
```

I tried changing the signature of `impl<const N: usize> std::ops::IndexMut<usize> for Bitmap<N>` to one similar to that of the Index implementation but I get errors. Then I tried a bunch of random things. None of them worked.

Comment: Do you really need to index by slices, not by range?
If so, you can implement SliceIndex and in theory you should be able to index by slices.

Comment: To assign to elements in a slice, you would use `.copy_from_slice()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting a slice from a range, as you did in previous attempt?

```rust
let slice = &test[2..5];
println!("{:?}", slice);
```

Now, same way, but from a range

```rust
let range = 2..5; 
let slice = &test[range];
println!("{:?}", slice);
```

Comment: Yes I noticed that this worked. I was trying to get it to work with assignment though as in &test[0..3] = [true,true,true]

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```rust
    let slice = [2..5].as_slice();
    println!("{:?}", &test[slice]);
```

The first line creates an array, initialized with the values 2,3,4,5, then creates a slice of that whole array, and binds that value to the variable `slice`.

The second line attempts to index `test` using that array. However, Rust does not provide any way to index an array of booleans (`[bool]`) using a slice of values generated from a range (`&[std::ops::Range<{integer}>]`). For that matter it does not provide any way index an array using a slice of anything.

What you could do is just not convert the range to an array in the first place:

```rust
    let range = 2..5;                  // Variable contains range from 2..5
    println!("{:?}", &test[range]);    // Index using range
```

You might be asking why Rust does not provide a means to index an array using an arbitrary array of indices. It might seem simple enough for your sample case, but what if the indices were disjoint (eg, `[2,7,8]`)? The array is a contiguous block of memory; a slice is a reference to a contiguous block of memory; and the range index operation returns a slice which references the underlying array, but what would it return if the indices were disjoint?

Comment: Would the down voter care to explain the reason for the downvote?